# transition and child node css

Tags: html, css

I cant understand why child div showed without fadein effect? I need when I hover on div ("black") then div (red) gradually appeared.. How do it?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sGxgv/)

HTML

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="ok"></div>  
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: black;
}
.ok {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    display: none;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;  
    opacity: 0;
}
.main:hover .ok{ 
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't apply the transition when changing the `display` property:

[Transitions on the display: property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property)

Just remove the display part, and it will work:

```
.ok {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;    
    transition: opacity 1s linear;  
    opacity: 0;
}
.main:hover .ok{ 
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sGxgv/1/